# Remember previous text searches history with positions after further text search

Tags: spacemacs, helm, search, helm-ag

TL;DR: Is it possible to go back and forth between different helm-ag searches, and keep the last visited position in each of them?

Using Spacemacs’ `spacemacs/helm-project-smart-do-search` (`SPC /` `pattern` `RET`, which I think is using [helm-ag](https://github.com/emacsorphanage/helm-ag) under the hood), I search for a text pattern in my project and go to the first match, and then `SPC r s C-n RET` to jump to subsequent matches. This is already more cumbersome than Vim’s `:Ggrep pattern` and then `:cn`, but still forgivable.

Recently, [I learned](https://thepugautomatic.com/2014/03/stacked-vim-searches-down-cold/) that in Vim, after doing another `:Ggrep pattern` in the middle of jumping through the matches of the first, I can go back to the first pattern with `:cold` and continue jumping (`:cn`/`:cp`) from where I left it off. **Is there an equivalent to this `:cold`/`:cnew` quickfix list history stack in Emacs?** (Specifically for helm-ag results or otherwise.)

As a side question, I would also like to know if my current workflow with `SPC /` (as described above) could be made more ergonomic without custom key bindings.

Comment: I'm not sure about helm-ag, but you may be able to resume the previous session using `M-x helm-resume` and cycle the history using `M-n/p`.